# Xamarin Studio and iOS: Modifying Root.plist at compile time

Tags: ios, xamarin

In my Debug build, I want to show some settings in the `Settings.bundle/Root.plist` file. Mainly, I want to show which backend environment the mobile app is using and make it configurable for testers.

In my Release build, I want to hide those settings in the `Settings.bundle/Root.plist` file since it will always point to production.

How can I modify the `Root.plist` file at compile time since it's not possible to modify the file at runtime?

Comment: I also answered another question related to yours that might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36795389/4984832

Comment: Thanks for the tip @SushiHangover. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: no problem, hope it helps... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS-X, there is a command called `PlistBuddy` that can list/change a `.plist` file.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
Usage: PlistBuddy [-cxh] <file.plist>
    -c "<command>" execute command, otherwise run in interactive mode
    -x output will be in the form of an xml plist where appropriate
    -h print the complete help info, with command guide
```

You could use a custom MSBuild task to modify the `.plist` using the `-c "Add"` or `-c "Set"` or `-c "Delete"` commands, run `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -h` to get help on using the various commands.

Something like from your iOS project root directory to output the `.plist` in xml format on the console:

---

```
find . -name "Root.plist" | xargs -n 1 -J % /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "Print" %
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Debug Settings</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>FalseValue</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>__monotouch_debug_enabled</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Enabled</string>
            <key>TrueValue</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>automatic</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>__monodevelop_host</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Xamarin Studio Host</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>AppSettings</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```